# TCPDF when It creates more than one page it does not print the next pages correctly

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

My output of my PDF page when it prints more than one page it does not print correctly. Please look at the example
Here is an example of the PDF file [expenses.pdf](http://notaryaccounting.com/expenses.pdf).
If you notice where the page starts printing on page 2 it overwrites itself.
Also it does not cut off the page on the first page above the category so it carry's the info onto the 2nd page.
Also there are only 19 items in this list yet it prints 5 pages and repeats the items.

```
class PDF extends tcpdf
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    $this->SetFont('Times', 'BI', 20, '', 'false');
    // Move to the right
   $this->Ln(5);
   $this->Cell(60);
   $this->Cell($w, $h=0, $txt='EXPENCE REPORT', $border=0, $ln=0, $align='', $fill=false, $link='', $stretch=0,   
   $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='M');
   $this->Line (0, 13, 210, 13, $style=array());
   // Line break
   $this->Ln(5);
}
 // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}
$pdf = new PDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage ($orientation='', $format='', $keepmargins=false, $tocpage=false);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak ($auto, $margin=16);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(true);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(true);   
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(10, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, 10);
// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 14, '', true);

$tbl_header = '<table cellspacing="3" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 8pt;">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';
$tbl = '';

$sql = "SELECT `expensetype`.`typeid`, `expensetype`.`exptype`, `expenses`.`expid`,`expenses`.`expdate`, `expenses`.`checktype`, `expenses`.`payee`,`expenses`.`details`, `expenses`.`amount` FROM `expensetype` INNER JOIN `expenses` ON
`expensetype`.`typeid` = `expenses`.`typeid`WHERE (`expenses`.`pid` = " . $pid . ")";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$expensetype = null;
foreach($result as $expense) {
if($expensetype != $expense['typeid']) {
   $exptype = $expense['exptype'];

$tbl .= ' 
<tr>
<td height="10" style="width: 100%;"></td>
</tr> 
<tr style="background-color:#E1E0E0">
<td height="20" style="width: 25%; text-align: left">Category:</td>
<td height="20" style="width: 75%; text-align: left">'.$exptype.'</td>
</tr>';

$tbl .= '
          <tr style="background-color:#CEC7C7">
            <th style="width: 20%">Date:</th>
            <th style="width: 30%">Payee:</th>
            <th style="width: 30%">Detalls:</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Amount:</th>
            </tr>';

$pdf->SetXY(2, 20);
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
 }

   $expdate=phpdate($expense['expdate']);

$tbl .= '
<tr>
<td style="width: 20%; text-align: center">'.$expdate.'</td> 
<td style="width: 30%; text-align: center">'.$expense['payee'].'</td>
<td style="width: 30%; text-align: center">'.$expense['details'].'</td>
<td style="width: 20%; text-align: center">'.$expense['amount'].'</td>
</tr>';

if($expensetype != $expense['typeid']) {
   $expensetype = $expense['typeid'];
    }
} 
$pdf->SetXY(2, 20);
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
// $tbl .= '
//<tr>
//<th style="width: 85%; text-align: right;">Total Amount:'  .$totalamount.' </th>
//</tr>';    
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();
```

This is what the script looks like now

```
$sql = "SELECT `expensetype`.`typeid`, `expensetype`.`exptype`, `expenses`.`expid`,`expenses`.`expdate`, `expenses`.`checktype`, `expenses`.`payee`,`expenses`.`details`, `expenses`.`amount` FROM `expensetype` INNER JOIN `expenses` ON
`expensetype`.`typeid` = `expenses`.`typeid`WHERE (`expenses`.`pid` = " . $pid . ")";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$expensetype = null;

foreach($result as $expense) {
$tbl = '';    
if($expensetype != $expense['typeid']) {
$exptype = $expense['exptype'];

$tbl .= ' 
<tr>
<td height="10" style="width: 100%;"></td>
</tr> 
<tr style="background-color:#E1E0E0">
<td height="20" style="width: 25%; text-align: left">Category:</td>
<td height="20" style="width: 75%; text-align: left">'.$exptype.'</td>
</tr>';

$tbl .= '
          <tr style="background-color:#CEC7C7">
            <th style="width: 20%">Date:</th>
            <th style="width: 30%">Payee:</th>
            <th style="width: 30%">Detalls:</th>
            <th style="width: 20%">Amount:</th>
            </tr>';

$pdf->SetXY(2, 20 + $pdf->GetY());
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
 }

   $expdate=phpdate($expense['expdate']);
$tbl = '';
$tbl .= '
<tr>
<td style="width: 20%; text-align: center">'.$expdate.'</td> 
<td style="width: 30%; text-align: center">'.$expense['payee'].'</td>
<td style="width: 30%; text-align: center">'.$expense['details'].'</td>
<td style="width: 20%; text-align: center">'.$expense['amount'].'</td>
</tr>';



$pdf->SetXY(2, 20 + $pdf->GetY());
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
if($expensetype != $expense['typeid']) {
   $expensetype = $expense['typeid'];
    }
}

$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 1):

Main cause is that you don't reinitialize the variable `$tbl`, that holds the body of your table every loop.

```
foreach($result as $expense) {
    $tbl = '';
```

should make your output more in the line that you want.

Now you've got solved the problem of

> Also there are only 19 items in this list yet it prints 5 pages and
>   repeats the items.

The overwriting occurs because you position your output absolut on the page with:

```
$pdf->SetXY(2, 20);
```

That's ok for the first time. Your next content (next loop) has to consider the actual Y position. You can get this with the `GetY()'  method.

```
$pdf->SetXY(2, 20 + $pdf->GetY());
```

should take care of that.

Comment: I added what you showed but it just made it only print one line check this link out http://notaryaccounting.com/expencetest.pdf

Comment: I already had $tbl = ''; added to the script just above the sql

Comment: @user3326386: I've edited my answer and gave a hint how to solve the remaining problem.

Comment: I looked at what GetY() does and this should work but I get a Fatal error: Call to undefined function GetY(). This does not make sense because it is a method in TCPDF. Any Ideas

Comment: @user3326386: I wasn't careful: It's got to be `$pdf->GetY()`, see edited code.

Comment: That made the data not overlap but now I have 12 pages for 19 rows of data. Take a look at the pdf file http://notaryaccounting.com/expencetest.pdf

Comment: @user3326386: Look at your content please: you've got 1 table in the first series, then 2, then 3, ... You've got to reset your `$tbl` variable at the beginning of the foreach loop as I said first.

Comment: It is really close I have added the $tbl = ''; in a couple of pleases. But it is still not working correctly. I have added the way the code looks now up where I asked the original question. And I new link as to what the script is outputting http://notaryaccounting.com/expencetest.pdf